# Grails losing image if not select new one on edit page

Tags: mysql, grails, spring-security

I'm making a website using spring security and grails 3.1.10. In this site I'm listing all image from database and show them at index. The problem is when I tried to edit one of those image. For example I want to just edit name but if I do not select an image this field become null.But I want to protect the image. How can i through this.

edit gsp

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="productImage"  id="productImage">
</div>
```

I tried to write a controller to protect old one but this one not work.

```
 def id=params.id
    Product old=Product.findById(params.id)
    def f = request.getFile('productImage')
    if(f.empty){
        print("file is empty")
        if(old.productImage){
            println("there is a file in database")
            product.productImage=old.productImage
        }}
```

Comment: The code does not really represent the issue you have outlined. You are listing all images then editing nothing in that gsp shows iteration or edit functionality as in how that would work

Answer (score 1):

I think I kind of understand there are a few issues here:

```
  //These two are the same
 Long id=params.id ? params.id as Long : null
 Long id=params.id ? params.long('id') : null
```

It says

```
 Long id= (is there a params.id ) 
   { yes ? }  ->  params.id as Long {otherwise :} -> null
```

findById should be used in rare cases:

```
 //You should never use findById unless an example would be   findByIdAndSomethingElse(id,somethingElse)
//  Product old=Product.findById(params.id)
```

Instead you should use (look int get read and load) get is the best since it ensures the record actually exists and where as read could return a cached copy (that may since be removed)  (read load are less resource intensive) worth reading up about - so sticking with get : and you may not have id so it should be wrapped around a further

```
if (id) {


    // Product old=Product.get(id)
   // Product old=Product.read(id)
   // Product old=Product.load(id)
   // You could have just done this which should convert params.id as long itself as the method
    Product old=Product.get params.id

def f = request.getFile('productImage')
if(f.empty){
    print("file is empty")
    if(old.productImage){
        println("there is a file in database")
        //I think this may be the issue:
        product.productImage=old.productImage
        //should this not be  ?
        product=old 
    }}
```

you have now outlined what old or product do after your statement which is the reason for my comment.

Does product or old then get sent as variables to the gsp page how are they represented ?

Also if this is your edit form;

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="productImage"  id="productImage">
</div>
```

This is missing  value

```
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="productImage"   
value="${someParams?.value}" id="productImage">
```

You state it returns null so it must be some other form field that you have not provided since this field actually has no value defined and therefore can never be a null.

Also notice

> value="${someParams?.value}"
>   vs 
>    value="${someParams.value}"

The ? is protecting the field from returning a null value. So upon start of a form where there may not be a value that would then save it showing null on the user's screen.

With all that said there appears to a be a conflict in what you say something going null vs what you are trying to set etc.. maybe a clash in what you want or maybe an easier way of putting it all

```
def f = request.getFile('productImage')
if (f.empty) {
    if (params.id) {
    Product old=Product.get(params.id as Long)
    print("file is empty")
    if (old.productImage) {
        println("there is a file in database")
        product.productImage=old.productImage
    } else {  
       //what should produce.productImage be now if no file and nothing on db ?
    }
   } else {
     //what should happen if there is no product.id ?
   }


  }  else {
     //what happens when there is a file provided - should that Product check be outside of this loop entirely should that file being returned be merged with the existing record ?
   }
```

There is lots there that will hopefully help you understand what is going wrong. With that all said this sort of stuff should really be done with the aid of a validation class this saves on you having to code out lots of logic in your controllers that in the end looks all too long winded and messy and hard to follow.

I will update an example project: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples a bit later today with an image example. Hopefully with a video to explain what I have added. Will leave a comment on here when done.

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples includes a very complex image bean that is discussed and shown on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATLQ7CCvPvI